# c++17 fast way for trans int to string with prefix '0'

Tags: c++, string, c++17, tostring

I want to trans an `int` into `string`.
I known under c++17, a better way is using `std::to_string`.

But now I want to fill the prefix with several '0'.
For example, `int i = 1`, `std::to_string(i)` is '1', but I want the result is '00001'(total lenght is 5).

I know using `sprintf` or `stringstream` may achieve that.
But which have a better performance or some other way?

Comment: *"which have a better performance"*. Generally, you have to measure.

Comment: My suspicion is that `sprintf()` is more efficient than `stringstream` (albeit also less secure -- use `snprintf()` at least), but the only real way to know is to test and measure both ways.  (And if you aren't able to measure any significant difference, then it doesn't much matter which you use)

Comment: Did you already try using [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) ?

Comment: I would recommend you use of `fmt` library, which is part of std since C++20.
`std::stringstream` sucks since you can't reserve buffer (often reallocation are expensive), but small string optimization should save the day for simple `int` values. So as Jarod42 suggest measure first, using data reflecting your scenario. It may turn out that `std::stringstream`  is fastest in your scenario.

Comment: @paolo Wouldn't it be hard to calculate where `first` should point and how would one deal with negative values?

Comment: @TedLyngmo You can write into a stack `char` buffer as long as the string representation of `INT_MIN` (plus the terminator), which should be the longest. You can aways start at writing at index `0`. `std::to_char` will return you one-past-last char you wrote. If you wrote more than 5 chars, you're fine (as the length of the sting should be at least 5). Otherwise, you can fill with `'0'` up to index `4` and then `std::rotate`. Does it make sense?

Comment: @paolo Sort of, but since transforming a result like `-1` will require additional processing to get it to become `-0001` it's starting to sound costly, but measuring would be needed of course. I'd compare it to a [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) based solution and to a `snprintf` based solution, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1b53bGMq1), to see which one that performs better.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Here you are a benchmark based on MarekR's where I added a possible implementation of the function I had in mind: https://quick-bench.com/q/0kdicPq6pxGaIwlUdJXb2rPwaU0. I don't have time to dig into this; feel free to do so, if you like :)

Comment: @paolo Very nice! That's seriously much faster than `snprintf` (even though I made the `snprintf` version a tiny bit faster by using `std::string buffer(6, '0');` to then `snprintf` directly into it). Too bad `std::format` isn't supported by the compiler at quick-bench yet. It would have been an interesting comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know something about your domain and don't need to check for errors, nothing gets faster than rolling your own.  For example if you know that your `int` is always in the range [0, 99'999], you could just:

```
std::string
convert(unsigned i)
{
    std::string r(5, '0');
    char* s = r.data() + 4;
    do
    {
        *s-- = static_cast<char>(i%10 + '0');
        i /= 10;
    } while (i > 0);
    return r;
}
```

General purpose libraries don't have the luxury of making such assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

Like it was mentioned in comments measure first!
I've [created repo](https://github.com/MarekR22/stackoverfloFastFill5ToInt) with multiple possible implementations to test them.

- std::ostringstream
- sprintf
- fmt::format
- std::to_chars
- full manual implementation (copy form Howard Hinnant) - fails if number do not fit within 5 characters.

Note that negative numbers are not covered (some bugs are expected)!

Here is [live demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/ZzlsgLDF84EvHq9_XngLJp6C_H4) (without fmt).

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <charconv>
#include <iomanip>

namespace fill5 {
namespace tag {
struct std_stream {};
struct std_to_chars {};
struct c_sprintf {};
struct manual {};
}

template<typename Tag>
std::string toString(int x);

namespace {
constexpr auto width = 5;
constexpr auto fill = '0';

std::string strBuf() {
    std::string r;
    r.resize(r.capacity());
    return r;
}
}

template<>
std::string toString<tag::std_stream>(int x)
{
    std::ostringstream r;
    r << std::setw(width) << std::setfill(fill) << x;
    return r.str();
}

template<>
std::string toString<tag::std_to_chars>(int value)
{
    auto r = strBuf();
    auto x = std::to_chars(r.data(), r.data() + r.size(), value);
    r.resize(x.ptr - r.data());
    if (r.size() < width) {
        r.insert(0, width - r.size(), fill);
    }
    return r;
}

template<>
std::string toString<tag::c_sprintf>(int value)
{
    auto r = strBuf();
    r.resize(std::sprintf(r.data(), "%05d", value));
    return r;
}

template<>
std::string toString<tag::manual>(int value)
{
    std::string r(5, '0');
    char* s = r.data() + 4;
    do
    {
        *s-- = char(value % 10) + '0';
        value /= 10;
    } while (value > 0);
    return r;
}
}

template <typename ImplTag>
void fill5ToString(benchmark::State& state) {
    constexpr int data[] {0, 1, 5, 13, 43, 343, 5344, 4234, 55555, 243422342};
    for (auto _ : state) {
        for (auto x : data) {
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(x);
            auto r = fill5::toString<ImplTag>(x);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(r);
        }
    }
}

using namespace fill5::tag;

BENCHMARK(fill5ToString<std_stream>);
BENCHMARK(fill5ToString<c_sprintf>);
BENCHMARK(fill5ToString<std_to_chars>);
BENCHMARK(fill5ToString<manual>);
```

Here are results from my machine (which covers `fmt` version):

```bash
% ./perf/Release/perf 
2022-06-28T01:36:36+02:00
Running ./perf/Release/perf
Run on (16 X 3600 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x8)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x8)
  L2 Unified 256 KiB (x8)
  L3 Unified 16384 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 1.13, 1.28, 1.12
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                            Time             CPU   Iterations
----------------------------------------------------------------------
fill5ToString<std_stream>         1782 ns         1782 ns       388470
fill5ToString<c_sprintf>           648 ns          648 ns      1070107
fill5ToString<std_to_chars>        227 ns          227 ns      3063779
fill5ToString<fmt>                 442 ns          442 ns      1584815
fill5ToString<manual>             46.7 ns         46.7 ns     14455075
```

As expected manual implementation rocks. `fmt` version is best from simple implementations and `std::ostringstream` version is "fast as a turtle".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `snprintf` or `stringstream` can both convert int to string with leading `0`.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;

std::string ss_to_string(int data) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) << data;
  return ss.str();
}

std::string snprint_to_string(int data) {
  char buffer[6];
  snprintf(buffer, 6, "%05d", data);
  return buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    ss_to_string(1);
  }
  auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  std::cout << "sstream version: "
            << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << "ms\n";

  auto t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    snprint_to_string(1);
  }
  auto t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  std::cout << "snprintf version: "
            << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t4 - t3).count() << "ms\n";
}
```

After measuring the `snprintf` version and `stringstream` version, it turns out that the `snprintf` implementation is more efficient.

```bash
sstream version: 60ms
snprintf version: 23ms
```

Comment: Please be aware that measuring performance in C++ is not so simple like you think, since there is "As if-rule". Compiler can remove lots of code which is tested. So your test may be invalid. Also did you use optimization flags?

Comment: Looks like difference is even bigger (ratio 4:1): https://quick-bench.com/q/dI0PGANZ-t1WKJyw-RkK2MVY37E

Comment: I'd be curious to see `std::format` and `std::to_chars` included

Comment: @Mgetz sadly support by compilers for `std::format` is still quite poor.

Comment: @MarekR Especially in C++17. :-)